# How do I discover where a mysterious click category event is on my site when it appears in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking

I've started to track button clicks on certain pages. I've created all parameters, which are both of required and optional.

The tracking works but I've detected another one click category in Google Analytics events report.  It is not one of my own click categories I created.  This mysterious category earns up to 90% of clicks on pages. How do I found out where it is implemented:

- I can't find, what clicks are tracked in this category
- I can't find this click category name in the source code
- I don't use tag manager

I'm looking for ways to find out where this click category is implemented and which clicks it tracks.

Comment: Could it be spam?   Google Analytics has recently had spammers hitting my Google Analytics pinger without ever visiting my site.   They were putting "visit  example.com" into all my reports.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been able to see which pages, hostnames, browser, and networks this event is coming from? This type of event sounds like spam to me. Also bolstered by the fact that they're soliciting your visit!

[This site](http://www.ohow.co/stop-www-event-tracking-com-referral-spam/) gives you good info on how to combat this nuisance.